# At least one of the properties should have a certain value in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have 2 objects in json schema like below

```
"object1": {
        "type": "number",
        "enum": [
            0,
            1
        ]
    },
    "object2": {
        "type": "number",
        "enum": [
            0,
            1
        ]
    }
```

At least one of object1 or object2 or both should be 1, how to achieve this criteria from json schema

Comment: Hello. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved using below

```
"anyOf": [
    {
        "properties": {
            "object1": {
                "enum": [
                    1
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "object2": {
                "enum": [
                    1
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: from JSON Schema Draft 6 onward, you can also use `”const”: 1` instead of `”enum”: [ 1 ]`. Both are equivalent however and `enum` is valid as well. `const` is only deemed “syntactic sugar”.